# How to show a custom error or warning message box in .NET Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I show message boxes with a "Ding!" sound and a red 'close' button in it? This is what I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to create some custom errors and warnings, but this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Ding!");
```

doesn't seem to give me any customization options.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Some text", "Some title", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Comment: MSDN: Other icons you can use : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon.aspx

Comment: now it's not supported MessageBoxIcon.Error. try something like MessageBox.Show("Some text", "Some title",
    MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Warning);

Answer (score 24):

**Try details:** use any option:

```
MessageBox.Show(
    "your message",
    "window title", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Warning // for Warning  
    //MessageBoxIcon.Error // for Error 
    //MessageBoxIcon.Information  // for Information
    //MessageBoxIcon.Question // for Question
);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
MessageBox.Show(
  "your message",
  "window title", 
  MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
  MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk //For Info Asterisk
  MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation //For triangle Warning 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add namespace if you are not using it:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Some text", "Some title", 
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Alternatively, you can add at the begining of your file:

```
using System.Windows.Forms
```

and then use (as stated in previous answers):

```
MessageBox.Show("Some text", "Some title", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```